# How to get if Azure slots swapping succeeded?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

After sending a swap action I'd like to know its progress. How to do it using Powershell? What event should I monitor using `Get-AzureRmLog`? I tried to check using `$_.resourceid -like "*Microsoft.Web/sites/examplesite" -and $_.OperationName.Value -eq 'Microsoft.Web/sites/write' -and $_.Status.Value -eq 'Succeeded'`. Worked once, but does not work now. See below.

```
> Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -SourceSlotName qa -DestinationSlotName production
> $r = get-azurermlog -ResourceGroupName examplegrp 3> $null 
> $r |  select { $_.eventtimestamp,$_.operationname.value,$_.status.value,$_.resourceid.substring(50) }

{2018-07-23 17:10:05, Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/examplesqlserver/databases/aatDb}
{2018-07-23 17:10:04, Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/examplesqlserver/databases/prodDb}
{2018-07-23 17:10:04, Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/examplesqlserver/databases/qaDb}
{2018-07-23 17:09:33, Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/examplesite/slots/aat}
{2018-07-23 17:09:27, Microsoft.Sql/servers/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/examplesqlserver}
{2018-07-23 17:08:52, Microsoft.Sql/servers/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/examplesqlserver}
{2018-07-23 17:08:17, Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/AppServicePlan-example}
{2018-07-23 17:07:53, Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/AppServicePlan-example}
{2018-07-23 17:07:51, Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write, Succeeded, a/resourcegroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/exampleaatsa}
{2018-07-23 17:00:19, Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action, Accepted, a/resourceGroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/examplesite/slots/qa}
{2018-07-23 17:00:17, Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action, Started, a/resourceGroups/examplegrp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/examplesite/slots/qa}
```

The solution suggested at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#automate-with-azure-powershell does not work. I'm getting nothing with `Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceGroup [resource group name] -StartTime [time] -Caller SlotSwapJobProcessor`. Version: Get-AzureRmLog 5.0.1 AzureRM.Insights.

Actually at the Azure portal also does not show useful events in Activity log under the group

Comment: Try removing the -caller parameter. It does return the list of logs. But the list is would be exhaustive as this  would show everything. We can try  filtering out by Resource Type = "App Services/Website" and operation =  "Swap web app slots"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$a = Get-AzureRmLog -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> | Where-Object { $_.operationname.value -contains "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/slotsswap/action" -and $_.Status.Value -eq 'Succeeded'} 
$a | select { $_.eventtimestamp,$_.operationname.value,$_.status.value,$_.resourceid.substring(50) }
```

[image]

Comment: Yet, I don't have `sites/slots/slotsswap/action` with `Succeeded` status. Only `Started` then `Accepted`. :( See above. I wonder why. But before that I had this.

Comment: @Artyom Could you check if it swap successfully in the portal?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Don't know what was the matter yesterday.