# Swap deployment slot using Switch-AzWebAppSlot

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-deployment-slots

I have the following script for swapping deployment slots:

```
            $functionApp = $functionAppName;
            Write-Host "Starting to swap $functionApp";
            Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction ApplySlotConfig
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
            Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction CompleteSlotSwap
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
            Write-Host "Completed swapping $functionApp";
```

Is there a way to verify that Switch-AzWebAppSlot has executed successfully or not before proceeding to the next line? For example:

```
status = Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction ApplySlotConfig

if (status = "Success")
{
  Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction CompleteSlotSwap
}
```

UPDATE:

I updated the script based on the suggested solution as follows:

```
try {
            $functionApp = "functionAppname";           
            Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction ApplySlotConfig
            $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
            $log = Get-AzLog -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -StartTime $date -Caller SlotSwapJobProcessor
            $status = $log[0].Status
            if ("Succeeded" -eq $status) {
                Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction CompleteSlotSwap
                $log = Get-AzLog -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -StartTime $date -Caller SlotSwapJobProcessor
                $status = $log[0].Status
                if ("Succeeded" -eq $status) {
                    Write-Host "Completed swapping $functionApp";
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Host "Failed to swap $functionApp"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Failed to swap $functionApp"
            }
}
catch
{
        Write-Host "Something went wrong, please try again..."
}
```

but I see no data in $log. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using the below script, I can get the status of last Slot Swap operation done on the application in Azure:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "<subscription-id>"


$functionApp = "KrishNet6FuncApp1205";
$resourceGroup = "HariTestRG";


Write-Host "Starting to swap $functionApp";
Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $functionApp -SourceSlotName production -DestinationSlotName staging -SwapWithPreviewAction ApplySlotConfig
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
Write-Host "Completed swapping $functionApp";

Get-AzLog -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -StartTime 2022-06-23 -Caller SlotSwapJobProcessor
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to store the status in a variable and check if status = success, proceed?

Comment: Yes! Refer to the [MSFT GitHub Azure Article](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip149.html) and [AzureRmLog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51490877) Where they have given the syntax and output of validation status whether the swapping succeeded.

Comment: can I specify StartTime without a hard coded value (get current date or something like that?)

Comment: Yes, you can use the `Get-Date` to get a `DateTime` object as specified in the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azlog?view=azps-0.10.0) of `Get-Azlog`

Comment: Also how do I get the recently executed swap status rather than showing the status of the swap occurred on a specific date

Comment: @user989988, the above result is the last swap operation I have done!

Comment: If I did multiple swaps, Get-AzLog -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -StartTime 2022-06-23 -Caller SlotSwapJobProcessor gives multiple results.

Comment: could you please give a try by giving the StartTime value as exact SubmissionTimeStamp/EventTimeStamp format using the Get-date cmdlet.

Comment: I have also done multiple slot swaps but for the above command, I got only one which is the recent slot swap operation details.

Comment: could you please check the UPDATE section and help with the issue?